# orden de Excepciones para validar fecha java

Tags: java, date, excepciones

me gustaría validar una fecha con el formato MM/DD/AA, mediante un programa, al que se le pase dicha fecha como parámetro, la divida a través de StringTokenizer en elementos, y tenga en cuenta las excepciones produciendo un error cuando es un elemento no numérico, si no se introdujo, o si se especifica una fecha imposible.

Encuentro un problema cuando creo la nueva excepción y la intento unir a la de RuntimeException para los elementos vacíos o que no son numéricos, me gustaría saber la mejor manera de juntarlas y organizarlas correctamente.

Gracias.

```
public class ValidaFecha {


    public class fechaNoValida extends Exception{
        public fechaNoValida(){ }
        public fechaNoValida(String cadena){
                 super(cadena); //Llama al constructor de Exception y le pasa el contenido de cadena
        }
    }

    public void validarFecha(String fecha) throws fechaNoValida{

        StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(fecha,"/");

    while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){

//            if(tokens.nextToken() == null || tokens.nextToken().isEmpty()){
//                throw new RuntimeException("Has introducido un valor nulo.");
//            }

            if(Integer.parseInt(tokens.nextToken()) <= 0){
                throw new fechaNoValida("Has introducido algún elemento negativo.");
            }

        }
    }

    public void mostrarFecha(String fecha) throws fechaNoValida{
        validarFecha(fecha);
        StringTokenizer tokens=new StringTokenizer(fecha,"/");
    while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){

            System.out.println(tokens.nextToken());

        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ValidaFecha prueba = new ValidaFecha();
        try{
            prueba.mostrarFecha("11/12/12");
        }catch(fechaNoValida e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }catch(RuntimeException ex){
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Necesitas hacerlo con `StringTokenizer`? De ser así, parece un ejercicio de clase. Porque sino podrías usar `SimpleDateFormat` que hace este trabajo por ti.

Comment: Hola @Luiggi Mendoza , efectivamente era un ejercicio de clase, ya que hace tiempo que dejé aparcado java para ponerme con PHP y olvidar muchos de los conceptos principales de java, mi idea es repasarlos, y con este ejercicio, aclarar mejor el funcionamiento de las excepciones que se evalúan juntas y de paso, repasar el StringTokenizer. Por lo que cualquier aclaración sería de ayuda. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validar una fecha es más que validar el formato, también tiene que tener en cuenta que el número de días corresponda con el número de mes, en el ejemplo anterior si dará por valida la fecha 99/99/123 lo cual no corresponde con el formato DD/MM/YY, se puede ampliar la versión anterior:

```
public void validarFecha(String fecha) throws fechaNoValida{

    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(fecha,"/");
    int pos = 0;
    int dia = 0;
    int mes = 0;
   while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
        /* Capturamos el Token para Validar */
        String token = tokens.nextToken();

        if(token == null || token.trim().length()<=0){
            throw new fechaNoValida("Has introducido un valor nulo o vacío.");
        }
        else
        {
          /*Caracter no númerico */
          if(Character.isLetter(token.charAt(0))){
                throw new fechaNoValida("Caracter " + token+  " no Númerico ");
          }
          else if (Integer.parseInt(token) <= 0){
              throw new fechaNoValida("Has introducido algún elemento negativo o cero.");
          }
          else if (pos > 2){
              throw new fechaNoValida("La fecha no corresponde al formato DD/MM/YY");
          }
          else if (pos == 0){
              //Validando el DD no puede ser mayor de 31
              dia = Integer.parseInt(token);
              if (dia > 31)
                throw new fechaNoValida("DD incorrecto");
          }
           else if (pos == 1){          
              //Validando el MM no puede ser mayor de 12
              mes = Integer.parseInt(token);
              if (mes > 12) {
                throw new fechaNoValida("MM incorrecto");
              }
              else {
                //Validando el día en función del mes, solo comprobamos los meses con menos de 31 dias
                switch mes{                 
                    case 2: // 29 dias
                        if (dia > 29)
                            throw new fechaNoValida("El día no corresponde al mes de febrero");
                        break;

                    case 4: // 30 dias
                    case 6: // 30 dias
                    case 9: // 30 dias
                    case 11: // 30 dias
                        if (dia > 30)
                            throw new fechaNoValida("El día no corresponde al mes " + mes);
                        break;

                }
              }
          }
          else if (pos == 2){
              //Validando el MM no puede ser mayor de 99
              if (Integer.parseInt(token) > 100)
                throw new fechaNoValida("YY incorrecto");
          }
          pos = pos + 1;
        }
        /* Imprimir el Token*/
        System.out.println(token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Algunas recomendaciones para su código :

- El método `mostrarFecha()` hace lo mismo que `validarFecha()` podría comprimir su lógica en un solo método
- Almacenar el `token` en un variable para realizar la validación correspondiente, porque el `nextToken()` retorna el siguiente token(aunque suene redundante) o sea que si ingresas `A/12/1212` tu validación `if` (comentada) haría lo siguiente

  ```
  if(tokens.nextToken() == null || tokens.nextToken().isEmpty())
   /* asignando valores haría la siguiente validación*/
  if(A == null || 12.isEmpty())
  ```

A continuación su método comprimido podría quedar así (Modificable para tener en cuenta algunas validaciones pero eso ya le dejo a su imaginación ):

```
 public void validarFecha(String fecha) throws fechaNoValida{

    StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(fecha,"/");
   while(tokens.hasMoreTokens()){
        /* Capturamos el Token para Validar */
        String token = tokens.nextToken();
        if(token == null || token.trim().length()<=0){
            throw new fechaNoValida("Has introducido un valor nulo o vacío.");
        }
        else
        {
          /*Caracter no númerico */
          if(Character.isLetter(token.charAt(0))){
                throw new fechaNoValida("Caracter " + token+  " no Númerico ");
           }
          else if (Integer.parseInt(token) <= 0){
              throw new fechaNoValida("Has introducido algún elemento negativo o cero.");
          }
        }
        /* Imprimir el Token*/
        System.out.println(token);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias de nuevo @Dev. Joel , ahora lo veo mucho más claro, y queda entendido todo, y perfectamente explicado.